# Application is not installing after resigning the app

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, jenkins, codesign

I have followed resigning of the app using this approach
[link](https://gist.github.com/chaitanyagupta/9a2a13f0a3e6755192f7)
When I sign the application using the code signing identity of same account,I am not facing any problem.

When I sign the application using the code signing identity of different account,the app is not installing.

```
**Find device logs below**

Aug  9 05:02:57 iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIClientConnection lookupUninstalledWithOptions:completion:]: Lookup uninstalled requested by atc (pid 40) with options (null)
Aug  9 05:02:57 iPhone atc[40] <Warning>: |error| Unable to create file lock.
Aug  9 05:02:58 iPhone CommCenter[79] <Notice>: Snapshot path [/var/wireless/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/Baseband/] was removed
Aug  9 05:02:58 iPhone crash_mover[2659] <Notice>: (Warn ) <crash_mover.m nr_isPaired:305> device is not paired
Aug  9 05:03:00 iPhone storebookkeeperd[138] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDDomainSyncedStorageController]  target sync date from client: 2016-08-08 23:33:10 +0000 (in 10.00 sec)
Aug  9 05:03:00 iPhone storebookkeeperd[138] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDDomainSyncedStorageController]  setting target date to: 2016-08-08 23:33:10 +0000 (in 62621512019.73 sec)
Aug  9 05:03:00 iPhone storebookkeeperd[138] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDDomainSyncedStorageController]  scheduling sync (via BackgroundTaskJob) 9.999694 seconds from now...
Aug  9 05:03:00 iPhone SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: could not find icon for representation -> com.testing.test1
Aug  9 05:03:00 iPhone SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
        Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
        Try this: 
            (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
            (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1521a4700 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x152956030]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x15295f610 )>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x152911190 H:[UIView:0x152956030]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x15295f610 )>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x152776570 H:|-(16)-[UIView:0x152853d80]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x152956030 )>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15290bac0 H:[UIView:0x152853d80]-(16)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x152956030 )>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x152831960 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x15295f610(0)]>"
    )

    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x15290bac0 H:[UIView:0x152853d80]-(16)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x152956030 )>

    Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
    The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
Aug  9 05:03:00 iPhone searchd[168] <Warning>: ====^^^^ DuetExpert missing data, count -> people:0 applicationDeepLinks:0 applications:8 requests:242 missingAllDataRequests:0
Aug  9 05:03:00 iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/tmp/com.apple.atc.Apps/com.testing.test1.app" type Placeholder (LSInstallType = 4) requested by atc (pid 40)
Aug  9 05:03:00 iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.testing.test1; Version=0.0.10, ShortVersion=(null)>
Aug  9 05:03:00 iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.testing.test1 at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0685BF39-E8C4-4D66-A5CF-EFD7CE29773C
Aug  9 05:03:00 iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.testing.test1 at /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55D4F9A3-DB4A-483F-A11E-E4CE58DE5184
Aug  9 05:03:00 iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful; Staging: 0.00s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.00s, Verifying: 0.01s; Overall: 0.14s
Aug  9 05:03:00 iPhone nesessionmanager[133] <Notice>: NESMPathControllerSession[com.apple.commcenter.ne.cellularusage:358E9214-5A59-4451-B74C-2D08546A5FAA]: Skip a start command from nehelper[108]: session in state connected
Aug  9 05:03:00 iPhone syncdefaultsd[2661] <Notice>: (Note ) SYDAccount: no account
Aug  9 05:03:00 iPhone syncdefaultsd[2661] <Notice>: (Note ) SYDBootAccount: no account (null)
Aug  9 05:03:00 iPhone syncdefaultsd[2661] <Notice>: (Note ) SYDPIMAccount: no account (null)
Aug  9 05:03:00 iPhone syncdefaultsd[2661] <Notice>: (Note ) SYDAlwaysOnAccount: no account (null)
Aug  9 05:03:01 iPhone tccd[103] <Notice>: Refusing client without bundle identifier (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/Support/medialibraryd)
Aug  9 05:03:01 iPhone tccd[103] <Notice>: Refusing client without bundle identifier (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/Support/medialibraryd)
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e247000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/test1.ipa" type Customer (LSInstallType = (null)) requested by atc (pid 40)
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e247000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.testing.test1; Version=0.0.10, ShortVersion=0.0.10>
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone profiled[153] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone profiled[153] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Updating MIS trust...
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone securityd[91] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone securityd[91] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone installd[50] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: MIS: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by provisioning profile 'SmartOffice Mobile Enterprise Dist'
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone installd[50] <Error>: 0x16e247000 +[MICodeSigningVerifier _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:]: 142: Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.2qAqVP/extracted/Payload/test1.app : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone installd[50] <Error>: 0x16e247000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Verification stage failed
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone atc[40] <Error>: 0x16e1bb000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke222: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.2qAqVP/extracted/Payload/test1.app : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)" UserInfo={LibMISErrorNumber=-402620394, LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, SourceFileLine=142, FunctionName=+[MICodeSigningVerifier _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:], NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.2qAqVP/extracted/Payload/test1.app : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)}
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone nsurlsessiond[115] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
        "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x1465658f0> com.testing.test1 (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55D4F9A3-DB4A-483F-A11E-E4CE58DE5184/com.testing.test1.app>"
    )
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone itunesstored[111] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
        "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x139146030> com.testing.test1 (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55D4F9A3-DB4A-483F-A11E-E4CE58DE5184/com.testing.test1.app>"
    )
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone iaptransportd[73] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
        "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x14f537910> com.testing.test1 (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55D4F9A3-DB4A-483F-A11E-E4CE58DE5184/com.testing.test1.app>"
    )
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone apsd[95] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
        "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x15f57a0b0> com.testing.test1 (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55D4F9A3-DB4A-483F-A11E-E4CE58DE5184/com.testing.test1.app>"
    )
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone atc[40] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
        "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x1378c3360> com.testing.test1 (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55D4F9A3-DB4A-483F-A11E-E4CE58DE5184/com.testing.test1.app>"
    )
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone SpringBoard[58] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
        "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x1528762f0> com.testing.test1 (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55D4F9A3-DB4A-483F-A11E-E4CE58DE5184/com.testing.test1.app>"
    )
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone BTServer[65] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
        "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x13fd3f680> com.testing.test1 (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55D4F9A3-DB4A-483F-A11E-E4CE58DE5184/com.testing.test1.app>"
    )
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone UserEventAgent[26] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
        "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x13dde4400> com.testing.test1 (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55D4F9A3-DB4A-483F-A11E-E4CE58DE5184/com.testing.test1.app>"
    )
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone passd[136] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
        "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x147d80a20> com.testing.test1 (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55D4F9A3-DB4A-483F-A11E-E4CE58DE5184/com.testing.test1.app>"
    )
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone homed[135] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
        "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x125e04010> com.testing.test1 (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55D4F9A3-DB4A-483F-A11E-E4CE58DE5184/com.testing.test1.app>"
    )
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone profiled[153] <Error>: [appinstallation] LaunchServices observer: Apps Failed be installed: (
        "<LSApplicationProxy: 0x13c55ee80> com.testing.test1 (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55D4F9A3-DB4A-483F-A11E-E4CE58DE5184/com.testing.test1.app>"
    )
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone lsd[86] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Unentitled vendor device identifier lookup for app com.testing.test1 by pid 40
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e247000 -[MIClientConnection uninstallIdentifiers:withOptions:completion:]: Uninstall requested by atc (pid 40) for identifier com.testing.test1 with options: (null)
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e247000 -[MIUninstaller _uninstallBundleWithIdentifier:error:]: Uninstalling identifier com.testing.test1
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e247000 -[MIUninstallNotifier performRemovalWithCompletionBlock:]: Destroying container with identifier com.testing.test1 at /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55D4F9A3-DB4A-483F-A11E-E4CE58DE5184
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e247000 -[MIUninstallNotifier performRemovalWithCompletionBlock:]: Destroying container with identifier com.testing.test1 at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0685BF39-E8C4-4D66-A5CF-EFD7CE29773C
Aug  9 05:03:03 iPhone nesessionmanager[133] <Notice>: NESMPathControllerSession[com.apple.commcenter.ne.cellularusage:358E9214-5A59-4451-B74C-2D08546A5FAA]: Skip a start command from nehelper[108]: session in state connected
Aug  9 05:03:04 iPhone mobile_assertion_agent[154] <Notice>: service_one_connection: Connection closed for client iTunes.
Aug  9 05:03:09 iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: AppleKeyStore: operation failed (pid: 44 sel: 34 ret: e00002bc '-536870212')
Aug  9 05:03:09 iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: AppleKeyStore: operation failed (pid: 44 sel: 34 ret: e00002bc '-536870212')
Aug  9 05:03:09 iPhone keybagd[44] <Error>: 0x16e1bb000 __handle_keystashverify_block_invoke: aks_stash_verify failed e00002bc
Aug  9 05:03:09 iPhone softwareupdateservicesd[178] <Error>: call_and_response: Error from server
Aug  9 05:03:09 iPhone keybagd[44] <Error>: 0x16e12f000 __handle_keystashverify_block_invoke: aks_stash_verify failed e00002bc
Aug  9 05:03:09 iPhone SpringBoard[58] <Error>: call_and_response: Error from server
Aug  9 05:03:09 iPhone softwareupdateservicesd[178] <Warning>: [autosu error]: SPI for AutoSU: probabilityVector is empty
Aug  9 05:03:10 iPhone storebookkeeperd[138] <Warning>: [UPP-SBDDomainSyncedStorageController]  running synchronizeImmediatelyWithCompletionHandler: now
Aug  9 05:03:10 iPhone storebookkeeperd[138] <Warning>: [StoreBookkeeper] -[SBKUniversalPlaybackPositionStore _onQueueRunTaskWithName:taskCompletionHandler:runTaskBlock:] _onQueueSync - beginning synchronize operation...
Aug  9 05:03:10 iPhone storebookkeeperd[138] <Warning>: [StoreBookkeeper] -[SBKUniversalPlaybackPositionStore _onQueueLoadBagContextWithCompletionHandler:] _onQueueLoadBag - load bag operation beginning...
Aug  9 05:03:10 iPhone storebookkeeperd[138] <Warning>: [StoreBookkeeper] __81-[SBKUniversalPlaybackPositionStore _onQueueLoadBagContextWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke413 _onQueueLoadBag - load bag completed.
Aug  9 05:03:10 iPhone storebookkeeperd[138] <Warning>: [StoreBookkeeper] __89-[SBKUniversalPlaybackPositionStore _onQueueSynchronizeImmediatelyWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke _onQueueSync - synchronize operation beginning...
Aug  9 05:03:11 iPhone storebookkeeperd[138] <Warning>: [StoreBookkeeper] __96-[SBKUniversalPlaybackPositionStore _onQueueRunTaskWithName:taskCompletionHandler:runTaskBlock:]_block_invoke281 _onQueueSync - synchronize completed. 
Aug  9 05:03:18 iPhone SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: [autosu error]: SPI for AutoSU: probabilityVector is empty
Aug  9 05:03:18 iPhone SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: [autosu error]: SPI for AutoSU: probabilityVector is empty
```

Comment: Can you please add device logs ?

Comment: Added, Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not changing the entitlements properly.

i.e 
team identifier present in *application identifier* and *keychain access group* might be the one that belongs old account.

You have to update those with the one for new account.

then

try signing that it'd work I guess

*FYI:*

Application identifier is the combination of team id and bundle id
team id you can find from the installed certificate in keychain